# Scala: zip a list with another list of types?

Tags: scala

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
val xs = List("a", "1", "5.3")
(xs zip List(String, Int, Double)).map{
   case (e, t) => e.asInstanceOf[t]
}
```

As you see, I am trying to parse a list of strings to proper types.

Of course the above does not work, specifically for the "String" part. The compiler complains that `error: object java.lang.String is not a value`.

**EDIT**
I understand this is not doable in the above way. Can you suggest a good way to achieve this?

Comment: What you call a list of types is actually a list of objects that happen to have the same name as some types (and the compilers tells you no such object exists with the name String). Types are not values that can be put in a list; they are compile-time information about values that help you avoid writing non-sensical code.

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet I understand. What I am trying to achieve is actually to convert a list of strings to proper types. I'll edit the original question to reflect this.

Comment: This still won't work. You're trying to manipulate types as values, which they are not. However, what you wish to do seems to convert strings to different pre-defined types, which could be done using conversion functions, rather than casting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to apply a list of converters `String => String`, `String => Int`, `String => Double` to your list of strings.

This can be done passing the actual converters (and not the types) to your list:

```
xs.zip(List(x => x, x => x.toInt, x => x.toDouble)).map {
  case (str, conv) => conv(str)
}
```

However, since elements of a list must have same type, this will give you a `List[Any]`, and you will loose all avantages of strong typing.

The easiest solution in my opinion would be to not try to do the conversions in a `List`, but rather one at a time, following your business logic:

```
val s: String = xs(0)
val i: Int = xs(1).toInt
val d: Double = xs(2).toDouble
```

If you insist on using `List`-like transformations, you might try your hand at shapeless `HList` and `Poly`, but it requires a strong basic understanding of type theory, so I'd rather not delve into it in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually write a legal equivalent to

```
(xs zip List(String, Int, Double)).map{
   case (e, t) => e.asInstanceOf[t]
}
```

It's

```
(xs zip List(classOf[String], classOf[Int], classOf[Double])).map{
   case (e, t) => t.cast(e)
}
```

But of course it throws an exception, as your original code would, because e.g. `"1"` is not an `Int`, it's a `String`.